# Can not read .xlsm file - POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have written a code to access .xlsm file but it fails to do so. I have tried the same file using both **XSSFWorkBook** and the Generic WorkBook which is done using **WorkBookFactory**.

## Scenario 1:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new  File(
                "/filename.xlsm"));
```

### Error:

The supplied spreadsheet seems to be an Encrypted .xlsx file. It must be decrypted before use by XSSF, it cannot be used by HSSF.

So I left the generic way of reading the file and used XSSF.

## Scenario 2:

```
 XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new
     File("/fileName.xlsm")));
```

### Error:

org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]

Both the scenarios do work on some .xlsm files. Properties and data with working and non working files are the same.

Can someone help in fixing this.?

Comment: The second exception is normally triggered when someone wraps the excel file in a zip file. Could that be it?

Comment: No, @Gagravarr. Its not zipped and its a macro enabled excel file.

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: @Gagravarr, I was using v3.9 and now I it changed to v3.12. After that it worked perfectly using WorkbookFactory. Thanks a lot for helping and please update the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer... You need to upgrade your version of Apache POI!

You can view the [Apache POI changelog here](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html), and see quite how many changes there have been since 3.9 came out 3 years ago. It's quite a number of pages of fixes! And you need at least one of those...